# Xenophobia against non-humans in the Old World

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

In the Warhammer Fantasy novels there is plenty of xenophobia - being born with heterochromia (eyes with two different colours) might be enough to attract the interest of the Witch Hunters. During the orchestrated "Lahmian Uprising", many women were burned at the stake just because they had pale skin (so they were suspected of being vampires). Yet I can't recall any widespread hate towards non-humans: elves, dwarves, halflings or occasional ogre that live within the human lands.

I don't mean that all non-humans are generally loved - there might be occasional tension and unfriendliness against individual characters (because the given elf is pompous, that dwarf is rude etc), but I can't recall any situation where mob/hunters would go against non-humans specifically only because they are different ("The crops have failed it's the elves fault!").

So are they any Witcher-style pogroms anywhere within Old World?

Comment: Usually, (if they're not at war with each other for some reason) the good guys get on pretty well with each other. There's probably some isolated instances of people trying to round up non-humans, but it would be a very bad idea. Dwarves and eleves would not take very kindly to it and no one would want to start a war.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a pogrom, but non-Humans are generally distrusted in Bretonnia, at leastt according to second edition of WFRP. There are no pogroms simply because almost no non-Humans risk living there...

Comment: IT would be great if you could provide any quotes from the source text!

Comment: With pleasure, but it will take a while, as I am away from my books today.  If noone provides a definite answer until that time, I will add this to the answer. :)

Comment: I think Bretonnians distrust all non-Bretonnians, whether they're humans from the Empire of elves from Athel Loren. Also, the Lady of the Lake was an elf goddess and Bretonnians worshiped her, so  she definitely wouldn't want them shipped elves off to a gulag.

Comment: But Bretonnians don't know who really is Lady of the Lake. Have they learned, they are worshipping an elf they would be rather shocked. But it's actually interesting, how much can she protect them(I remember only rule not to try to take over Athel Loren) without sounding suspicious. It could be worth a separate question...